# React State Property referring to properties in own scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there a way for a property in the React state object to refer to it's own properties? Like in the example below:

```
this.state = {
    currentTotal: 30,
    columnLength: Math.ceil(this.currentTotal / 3), // Getting NaN.
}
```

Comment: Use set state with a callback function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `this.currentTotal` is undefined, which will result in a NaN during this arithmetic: `this.currentTotal / 3`.

There are a few ways to resolve this, but the perhaps the simplest solution is to just defer the `Math.ceil(this.currentTotal / 3)` calculation til after your components `state` is fully initialised like so:

```js
class Component {

  constructor() {
  
    const state = {
      currentTotal: 30,
      columnLength: 0
    }
    
    // Defer calculation til after state has been initialised
    state.columnLength = Math.ceil(state.currentTotal / 3)
    
    // Assign your initialised to the component
    this.state = state

    console.log( this.state.columnLength )
  }
  
}

new Component()
```

Comment: In React, `state` and `props` are immutable.

Comment: Component `state` can be mutated in the component's constructor

Comment: note that this `const state.columnLength` is invalid js. try removing the `const`

Comment: @JayHarris good spotting - thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

since you already need a currentTotal, I think this solution would be the most elegant

```
constructor() {
  const currentTotal = 30; // initialization
  this.state = {
    currentTotal,
    columnLength: Math.ceil(currentTotal / 3),
  }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, as the name suggests - currentTotal value may change.

Comment: @Abbadiah if it can change, there is no point of puting it in the constructor aint it ? The OP would ultimately need to use `setStates`. Also the selected answer does the same thing as mine, just with more lines of code

Answer (score -3):

We do usually to implement switch.

```
this.setState({ isOpen:!this.state.isOpen });
```

Mutate state using setState only.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code doesn't run

Comment: yeah, `{ }` are missing

Comment: Also note: [Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)